# Include content of a page inside one markdown file in another markdown file when generating documentation using Doxygen

Tags: markdown, doxygen

I am using markdown file (*.md) and Doxygen tool to process these files and generate documentation.

### File1.md

Some content A
Some content B

\page ABC Title of ABC

Then I am using \subpage to include the contents of ABC like below

### File2.md

Some content C
Some content D

\section Mysection

\subpage ABC

The generated documentation places a link and on clicking the link the contents of page ABC are shown.
Can we show the contents of ABC directly in File2 instead of a link to ABC?

I asked ChatGPT and searched all pages. Could not succeed.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? It just creates the hierarchy, but maybe you should have a look at the commands `include{doc}` and `\snippet{doc}`

Comment: Hi Albert, We are using 1.9.2. I tried include and snippet, both did not work. I just get a small box with no content inside.

Comment: Doxygen version 1.9.2 is a bit older (August 18, 2021) the current doxygen version is 1.9.6. You wrote "I tried include and snippet, both did not work. I just get a small box with no content inside." please add an example to the original question of this attempt so we can see what you have tried (including the doxygen settings different from the default settings, i.e. the result of `doxygen -x Doxyfile`).